# After override the field as compute it's not working

Tags: python, odoo-9

I did some changes in product.template and override the field like this

```
list_price = fields.Float(copy=False, string='Sale Price',  store=True,compute='_calculate_sale_price',
                              help='compute cost as per gun_dealer', default=0.00)
```

and the compute methods is like

```
@api.multi
    @api.depends('profit_per_unit', 'estimated_shipping_charges'
                 , 'flat_rate_charges', 'list_price')
    def _calculate_sale_price(self):

        if self.category_parent_id == 33:
                self.list_price = self.standard_price+self.profit_per_unit+ \
                                  self.estimated_shipping_charges

        else:
            self.list_price = self.standard_price+self.profit_per_unit-self.collected_shipping_charges + \
                                  self.flat_rate_charges
```

But after doing this the Unit Price from sale order's order line is not grabbing value of Sales Price from product.template

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION. But I cant really put this suggestion in a comment.

I am not sure if you should use list_price in your depends decorator arguments. Try placing some logging in and see what is happening when you load the page.

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@api.multi
@api.depends('profit_per_unit', 'estimated_shipping_charges', 'flat_rate_charges')
def _calculate_sale_price(self):
    _logger.info("EXECUTING _calculate_sale_price() function")
    if self.category_parent_id == 33:
        _logger.info("CATEGORY PARENT ID IS 33!")
        _logger.info("list_price = {} + {} + {}".format(self.standard_price, self.profit_per_unit, self.estimated_shipping_charges))
        self.list_price = self.standard_price+self.profit_per_unit + self.estimated_shipping_charges
    else:
        _logger.info("CATEGORY PARENT ID IS NOT 33! REPEAT NOT")
        _logger.info("list_price = {} + {} + {} - {} + {}".format(self.standard_price, self.profit_per_unit, self.collected_shipping_charges, self.flat_rate_charges))
        self.list_price = self.standard_price + self.profit_per_unit -self.collected_shipping_charges + self.flat_rate_charges
```

Comment: In  logger:-INFO test13 openerp.addons.client_models.product.calculate_price: EXECUTING _calculate_sale_price() function

Comment: Really, so it starts the function. The next line it evaluates and it does not print either the 33 or the catchall else statement? With no additional error? Maybe python's if else needs a fallback for else.

Comment: Just in case else does not cover everything `else` that could occur.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't help my self.

Comment: You really should also see either your `if` or `else` statements printing logs. Its practically impossible that they are not unless you get an error.

Comment: Ya there is no statement is printing neither for if nor for the else no error is showing and calculation is giving desired result

Comment: Well, I am deeply troubled by the logging not printing. I dont know how I am going to sleep tonight however if it is working for you I would appreciate if you up vote my work.

Comment: It might be taking out the list_price resolved the issue. Or something you have done that you were not aware of. I cant really be sure. Once you have it working I might remove all the logging though. No need unless you are debugging.